# XML properties: match_parent and fill_parent. It seems that both are the same. Is there any difference between them?

Tags: android

I have downgraded my API to 7 and cannot figure out the difference in padding or sizes in either length or width in regards to match_parent and fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

FILL_PARENT (renamed in favour of MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8+)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

FILL_PARENT has been renamed to MATCH_PARENT for API level above 8 to avoid the confusion in the developers

Comment: `... to avoid the confusion ...` Well, it seems the sentence should be `... to add confusion ...`